# MGLMapView does not show any object added to the view controller

Tags: ios, swift, object, uiview, mapbox

I have properly set up an Viewcontroller containing an `UIView` with class `"MGLMapView"`, what I am trying add an button to the Viewcontroller, but when I run the app the button does not show.

Same if I do an external Viewcontroller and overlay the MapViewController, it runs, but it does not show.

**Why is that? have anybody had a similar problem? and how do I solve it?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you haven’t added the button below the map view? Check in the outline view in IB.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the `MGLMapView` but it should adhere to same rules as any other  `UIView` object.

This example is based on a `MKMapView` but it should be analog for `MGMapView`. Put this code in your VC and add `setUpViews()` to your `viewDidLoad()` method.

Note: this code should put the `MKMapView` at the bottom of the view stack and the map view should take up the entire view (except the top 64 pts--I assumed a `UINavigationView` might be in use--if not just change 64.0 to 0.0 in the constraints). Then it adds a `UIButton` on top of the `MKMapView` centered in the x direction with a width of 150 a height of 40 and 20 from the bottom of the view.

```
let map: MKMapView = {
    let view = MKMapView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

let button: UIButton = {
    let view = UIButton()
    // Add or change attributes as you need
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

fileprivate func setUpViews(){
    // Add the map first
    self.view.addSubview(map)
    // Add the button now it will be on top of the map view
    self.view.addSubview(button)
    map.delegate = self;

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        map.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 64.0),
        map.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),
        map.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
        map.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor)
        ])


    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0),
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150.0),
        button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
        ])
}
```